# What is the difference between a block producer and a validator node? and how is this linked with 'validators' needing to pay for sandwich attacks

Tags: blockchain, transactions, blocks, validators

Are these they same or are these distinct entities.
I'm often confused when I find in articles that validators
need to pay (increased) transactions fees for a trade to be
frontrun or be sandwiched. If validators were block producers,
then they should not need to pay an additional fee to include their
own transactions in a block. Is this correct?
I guess I'm confused about the process and terminology.

I assume validators are nodes that scoop up transactions in mempool,
and then validate before packaging them into a block. Hence they
are block producers. (I must be wrong.)